# Override Textarea in Django without models. Only in forms

Tags: python, django

I want to change the default size of Textarea. I read: 
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Textarea][1]
But I don't know how can I override it

## MY CODE:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 

class KarForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea,
        label="",
    )
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import KarelForm

def home(request):
    form = KarForm()
    context = {
    "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances). You can add attributes like classes or others, as the example there:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'})) # then you define the class in your css file
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '40'}))
```